# How to show Last Logon UserName in a logon dialogbox using C++ win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog, gina

i am using  C++ win32 API.

i have a gina logon dialogbox.

it contains a username textbox.

i want to show the last logon username in that textbox,when the system after restarted.

How can i get it?

Comment: Save it to file, save it in the registry. What are you tried?

Comment: @ Aesthete :stored in registry.if that system has more than one user,that time how can i know which user is logged on last time?

Comment: What @Aesthete means is that you store to `HKLM`, i.e. a shared location.

Comment: @ David :yes,in XP only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using system logon dialogbox (gina) you can use group policy to configure it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324740

Set it to false to prevent username to be hidden.